# Python: How do I use only 1 column when using multiple text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am using Python3 Notebook.  I am using multiple text files with multiple columns. How do I use only the first column of all 3 text files?

Text File Example:

```
Corey       1     765
Mike        2     675
John        3     645
Tom         4     234
Ben         5     134
Corey       6     646
Mike        7     543
John        8     324
```

The code I run tells me how many times each name occurs. But it also counts the numbers as well. How do I get it to only count the names in column 1?

```css
import re
import csv
filelist = ['D.txt','A.txt','S.txt']
wordbank = {}
for file in filelist:
    article_one = re.findall('\w+', open(file,).read().lower())

    for word in article_one:
        word = word.lower().strip(string.punctuation)
        if word not in wordbank:
            wordbank[word] = 1
        else:
            wordbank[word] += 1
        
sortedwords = sorted(wordbank.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        
for word in sortedwords:
    print (word[1], word[0])
```

My code above

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: The code snippet IS NOT what you apparently think it is. Pasting your code in the edit window, selecting it with the mouse and finally clicking the `{}` icon over the edit window  is all you need for Python code. If I'm not mistaken, code snippets are for HTML/javascript code excerpts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series()
for file in filelist:
   data2  = pd.read_csv(file, sep=" ", header = None, usecols =[0])
   data   = pd.concat((data,data2[0].str.lower(), axis=0) 

yourData  = dict(pd.Series(data).value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iPython Panda I was able to easily and quickly analyze all text files.

[Jupyter Notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%202%20-%20Selecting%20data%20&%20finding%20the%20most%20common%20complaint%20type.ipynb)

Code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
dft = pd.read_csv('sample.txt')
dft['Column'].value_counts()
```